# ios FCM messaging didReceiveRemoteMessage not called

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to use FCM to send notifications and data messages to iOS Devices.

All works fine, but for some reason the delegate method `messaging didReceiveRemoteMessage` is never called. Therefore I cannot get data messages when the app is in the foreground... I tried it with and without a notification block beside the data. So the message I am sending looks like this:

```
{'message': {
    'token': 'mytokenstandshere',
    'notification': {
        'body': 'message',
        'title': 'title'},
    'data': {
        'datafield': 'datavalue',
        'datafield2': 'datavalue2'}
}}
```

I tried all possibilities (without notification, without data, with both). Notification is working without problems, but the data block is not appearing in clean data messages.

I just want to have this running on iOS 11+. But I even tried it with the parts for iOS 9 and 10 from the docs from google.

This is my AppDelegate:

```
@

UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        Hardware.start()

        Preferences.initDefaults()

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

        Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


        return true
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("new Token: \(fcmToken)")
        Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: TOPIC_ALL_MESSAGES)

        NotificationSettingsListener.start()
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Got a remote")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)

    }

}

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([.alert])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing:

`application(_: didReceiveRemoteNotification: fetchCompletionHandler:)`

I believe that's required for handling. [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added this method, it's called but still no call of the delegate method `messaging(_ messaging:, didReceive remoteMessage:)`. It seems that somehow swizzling is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have to assign Firebase messaging delegate in `AppDelegate.m`

```
[FIRMessaging messaging].delegate = self;
```